# Different values of md5 sum from script and command line

Tags: linux, bash, macos

I write a bash script to automate things. I need to get an md5 sum of the string. However, the script is giving me a different (wrong) sum that command in the terminal. Why is the difference? I work on macOS.

Command line:

`echo -n "test" | md5`

output (correct):
`098f6bcd4621d373cade4e832627b4f6`

Bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

URLMD5=`echo -n "test" | md5`
echo $URLMD5
```

output (wrong):
`a2a2862cba31e1cdeeaccf9937a248d2`

### EDIT:

I just put the script @ linux machine, change `md5` to `md5sum` and it gives me correct value of `098f6bcd4621d373cade4e832627b4f6`

Comment: I'm guessing one of the many reasons to avoid `echo -n`. You want `printf` instead. (Also, backticks are cumbersome and have some iffy corner cases; the modern command substitution syntax has been standard for 20+ years IIRC.)

Comment: explanation of @tripleee comment relies in the echo man page

     Some shells may provide a builtin echo command which is similar or iden-
     tical to this utility.  Most notably, the builtin echo in sh(1) does not
     accept the -n option.  Consult the builtin(1) manual page.

Comment: Thank you guys for explanation!